# Getting xml data where attribute equals number

Tags: php, xml, find

I am trying to implement the Expedia API and I have run into an issue. I need to get the description tag of a parent tag with a certain attribute number. This is what I have tried and it is not working:

```
$data->RoomTypes->RoomType['roomCode="17918"']->description;
```

I do not know if this is the right syntax. If I were going to look for it in mysql it would look something like this:

```
mysql_query("SELECT description FROM RoomType WHERE roomCode = '17918'");
```

How would I go about doing this in xml with php?? Any help would be greatly appreciated!! Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, for XML queries, node attributes must be prefaced with a `@` for matching. You haven't specified what XML library you're using but if it's following conventions/standards, you'd probably want

```
$data->RoomTypes->RoomType['@roomCode="17918"']->description;
                            ^---
```

instead.

Comment: It did not work :(... I know the xml library is working because I can get any other data from it. using the same syntax.. just can't seem to find this. Thank you though!

Comment: There are various RoomType responses... could this affect it somehow? Should I place it into a loop?